# Insert to an UUID column with a foreign constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I have the following table structure & data:

`votes` table

```
season | episode | UUID    | vote
1      | 1       | X-X-X-X | 1
1      | 1       | Y-Y-Y-Y | -1
```

`users` table

```
UUID    | name
X-X-X-X | Jon
Y-Y-Y-Y | Sam
Z-Z-Z-Z | Tim
```

In the `votes` table, after running

```
ALTER TABLE votes ADD PRIMARY KEY (season, episode, UUID);
ALTER TABLE votes ADD INDEX (UUID);
ALTER TABLE votes ADD FOREIGN KEY (UUID) REFERENCES user (UUID)
                           ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and trying to insert an entry like this:

```
season, episode, UUID,      vote
1,      1,       'Z-Z-Z-Z', 1
```

into said table, the following error greeted me:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (voting, CONSTRAINT `constraint_name` FOREIGN KEY (UUID) REFERENCES users (UUID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I'd like to keep the UUID linked to the `users` table while not allowing multiple votes per same season - episode - UUID combination, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was adding the data using phpMyAdmin's Insert tab, and it automatically selected `UUID` from the Functions drop-down, which altered the data I wanted to insert. Setting the drop-down to an empty value left my inserted value alone and it was added just fine.